# Using apache-arrow in a browser application - Typescript compiler errors

Tags: typescript, apache-arrow

Attempting to use apache-arrow within a browser application, but typescript compiler throws the following errors in some of arrow's .d.ts files

```
import { Table } from "../node_modules/@apache-arrow/es2015-esm/Arrow";
export class SomeClass {
.
.
constructor() {
const t = Table.from('');
}
```

**node_modules/@apache-arrow/es2015-esm/column.d.ts:14:22** - error TS2417: Class static side 'typeof Column' incorrectly extends base class static side 'typeof Chunked'.
  Types of property 'new' are incompatible.

**node_modules/@apache-arrow/es2015-esm/ipc/reader.d.ts:238:5** - error TS2717: Subsequent property declarations must have the same type.  Property 'schema' must be of type 'Schema', but here has type 'Schema'.

238     schema: Schema;

**node_modules/@apache-arrow/es2015-esm/recordbatch.d.ts:17:18** - error TS2430: Interface 'RecordBatch' incorrectly extends interface 'StructVector'.
  The types of 'slice(...).clone' are incompatible between these types.

the tsconfig.json file looks like

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target":"ES6",
        "outDir": "dist",
        "baseUrl": "src/"
    },
    "exclude": ["dist"],
    "include": ["src/*.ts"]
}
```

Comment: Seems to have been answered here, but I can't yet verify: https://github.com/apache/arrow/issues/9752 Note also that there's a recommendation to ask on the user mailing list: https://arrow.apache.org/docs/developers/contributing.html#join-the-mailing-lists